# Azure WebApp AD Authentication - Group Access

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I've got one question about Azure Enterprise Apps and how to give access to one app for a special user/group.

My Setup:
One Azure WebApp (Angular) with ADAL (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)

After that I have created an App in AzureAD via ExpressSetup in the App-Configuration.

Evertything works fine and every user can log in to this app.
But how can I delegate the login for example to a special user or group?

In the settings of my Enterprise Application in AzureAD I've added three users unter "Users and groups" but anyway all other users has access to the App.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you also specified in the service principal (=Enterprise app) that user assignment is required?

Comment: Yes. "User assignment required" is set to "Yes"

Comment: omg, I think I've got it. I checked up my ADAL-confid in my angular app and I saw that there was another AzureAD-EnterpriseApp configured as in te Authentication-Settings of my AzureApp in the Portal. And in this EnterpriseApp was the user assigned set to "No". For testing I changed it to "Yes" and now it seems to work. Thank you!! Now I only have to change all configuration to one AzureAD Enterprise app...I don't know why I have configured two...